# Simple program using loops (Beginning Java)

Tags: java, loops

I have to write a program using loops that calculates the sum of all odd numbers between a and b (inclusive), where a and b are inputs.

I made this (below) and it works fine, but I noticed one problem with it: when i enter a larger number followed by a smaller number for the inputs, it returns 0, but when i enter the smaller number first it works perfectly. Any quick fixes for this? :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ComputeSumAAndB
{

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
       System.out.print("Please enter 2 integers: "); //prompts user for ints
       int a = in.nextInt(); 
       int b = in.nextInt();
       int sum = 0;

       for (int j = a; j <= b; j++)
       {
           if (j % 2 == 1)
             sum += j;
       }
       System.out.println("The sum of all odd numbers (inclusive) between " + a + " and "+ b + " is " + sum);
   }
}
```

Comment: just two input not need to have for loop and you also can use array instead.

Comment: Use if (j % 2 == 1) it is not enough to check whether the num is odd. e.g a = -5, b =0; What will be the result? it is zero.
You need to change the condition to if(!(j%2 == 0)) Then you will get the expected result.

Comment: This question has several good answers.  You should consider marking one of them as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

```
int temp;
if(a > b) {
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Put this right before your `for` loop starts.

---

The `if` checks whether `a` (the first number entered) is larger than `b`.  If it is, it swaps `a` and `b`.  Now your `for` loop will always start with the smallest number and iterate up to the larger number (because after this `if`, `a` will always be the smaller number).

Using this method has the added side effect of making your output make sense.  Your output will now always say: `"between [smaller number] and [larger number]"`.

rolfl's answer is more elegant and works perfectly fine, but when the user enters the larger number first, your output may look kind of weird: `"between [larger number] and [smaller number]"`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the smaller and larger inputs by using the [Math.min()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28int,%20int%29) and [Math.max](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max%28int,%20int%29) functions....

```
for (int j = Math.min(a,b); j <= Math.max(a,b); j++) {
    if (j % 2 == 1) {
        sum += j;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because **A** is larger than **B** in the **for** loop, you have it iterate while **A** is less than or equal to **B**.

You could do what nhgrif says but it's changing your data.. But he is correct.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are first expecting for the `a` input (inferior limit) and then the `b` (superior). When your program reaches the `for`, `j = a` so the condition `a <= b` is False, if the first input is larger. In other words it never enters the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should do the following 2 things:

1  It is just just like **rolfl** mentioned above. You need to put the min and max in the right place in loop.

for (int j = Math.min(a,b); j <= Math.max(a,b); j++) 
{

```
if (j % 2 == 1) {
    sum += j;
}
```

}

2 Use **if (j % 2 == 1)** it is not enough to check whether the num is odd.

e.g.

**a = -5**, **b =0;**
 What will be the result?

```
    int sum = 0;
    for(int j=-5;j<0;j++)
    {
        if(j%2 == 1)
        {
            sum+=j;
        }
    }
```

The value for sum will be 0.

We need to change the condition to **if(!(j%2 == 0))** Then you will get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are first expecting for the a input (inferior limit) and then the b (superior). When your program reaches the for, j = a so the condition a <= b is False, if the first input is larger. In other words it never enters the for loop.